# Mongodb: Is it possible to run map-reduce command and query strings as integers

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

So I have the following PHP code which runs a map-reduce command on a MongoDB database collection:

```
$map = new MongoCode("function() { emit(this.app, this.bytes); }");
$reduce = new MongoCode("function(k, vals) { ".
    "var sum = 0;".
    "for (var i in vals) {".
        "sum += vals[i];".
    "}".
    "return sum; }");

$dateAdded = mktime(0,0,0,5,1,2015);
//echo $dateAdded." = ".date("r",$dateAdded)."<br>\n";

$request = $db->command(array(
    "mapreduce" => "log",
    "map" => $map,
    "reduce" => $reduce,
    "query" => array("event" => "destroy", "systimelong" => array('$gt' => $dateAdded)),
    "out" => array("inline" => 1)));

    var_dump($request);
```

This actually works really great when the data is stored in the database as an integer.  But sometimes the data gets stored as a string.  Why?  Thats another story that cant be changed right now.  Ultimately it will be an integer, but I'd really like to know if and how I can modify this to handle the cases that the data is a string just in case it ever happens.

Since Mongo uses Javscript I feel like I should be able to use the `parseInt()` function inside the `$map` and/or`$reduce` functions, but it doesn't seem to be working.

Also, how would I handle the query?  The systimelong field is just unixtime, and I am using the PHP `mktime()` function to generate a integer value for the beginning of the month.  Again, it works great then comparing integers, but I need to first convert the string value.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried `$map = new MongoCode("function() { var converted_bytes = parseInt(this.bytes); emit(this.app, converted_bytes); }");`?

Comment: Right...as I thought that works just fine, but I really need to do the same thing in the query portion

Comment: This seems to work:  `$map = new MongoCode("function() {
     if (this.systimelong >= ".$dateAdded."){
        emit(this.app, parseInt(this.bytes));
     }
     }");` but I am unsure if I will take a performance hit or not.  Any thoughts?

Comment: Weird - Once I add the `parseInt()` function to the `this.systimelong` it fails if the value is NOT a string.  Shouldn't `parseInt()` return an int value regardless if you feed it a string or an int?